# Когда нужно вызывать метод paginate для оформления постраничной навигации?

Tags: php, laravel

Помогите разобраться, куда впихнуть метод `->paginate(10)`.
Это запрос к БД:

```
public function getAllNews()
{
    return $this->orderBy('seriatim', 'desc')->where(['active' => 1])->get();
}
```

Это вызов метода получения всех новостей в контроллере:

```
$Allnews = $news->getAllNews()->toArray();

$i = 0;
foreach ($Allnews as $value) {
    $value['created_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value['created_at'])->format('d.m.Y / H:i:s');
    $Allnews[$i]['date'] = $value['created_at'];
    $i++;
}
```

После вызова метода `getAllNews()`, я с помощью, `foreach` в тот же массив добавляю ключ с нужным форматом даты и времени.
Ну и затем, создаю переменную для вьюхи:

```
$data = [
    'Allnews'       => $Allnews,
    'MainMenu'      => $menu->getMainOptions()->toArray(),
    'SubMenu'       => $subm->getSubOptions()->toArray(),
];
```

Как здесь осуществить пагинацию новостей?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильный подход в принципе. Вы сначала получаете всё новости (а их может быть очень много) переводите его в массив и перебираете все элементы массива для простой задачи.

Добавьте метод `date` в модель. Содержание метода примерно такое:

```
public function date()
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->created_at)->format('d.m.Y / H:i:s');
}
```

Теперь вам не нужно будет переводить в массив и перебирать элементы. Применяйте спокойно метод `->paginate(10)` и в нужный момент вызывайте ваш метод `->date()`

Comment: Спасибо! С пагинацией разобрался с горем попалам!

Comment: Теперь создал в Модели, метод date, но обращение в контроллере не пашет. $Allnews = $news->getAllNews()->date(); ругается на такую строку тем, что "Метода date() не существует" -=(((

Comment: @overtheman $news->getAllNews() - получает все строки новостей(грубо говоря массив). Когда будете выводить их на странице (например через foreach) вызывайте для каждой строки метод date().

Comment: Так же порекомендую использовать paginate() вместо get() так вы будете получать не все записи а только те что вам нужны.

Comment: Вижу не рекомендуется благодарить сообщениями. Но увы повысить репутацию не могу -=(( со всем разобрался, всё работает! Спасибо за помощь, очень признателен!

Comment: @overtheman просто отметь ответ правильным